# Coerce repaint of the current swiped item in Telerik ListView for Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, telerik, repaint

To make a Minimal Reproducible Sample I have created a bound `Record` class and when this item is swiped it reveals the `[$]` button. Tapping the button successfully closes the swipe and updates the list item using this code:

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get; }
private void OnClick(Record record) => onToggle(record);

bool _toggled = false;
private void onToggle(Record record)
{
    _toggled = !_toggled;
    if(_toggled)
    {
        Title = "Toggled";
        BackgroundColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }
    else
    {
        Title = "Normal";
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    ListView.EndItemSwipe();
}
```

[image: Auto-close flow graphic]

So the bindings are OK but what I *really* want to do is leave the item in the Swiped state and have the background color **applied immediately** to the card. Commenting out the `\\ ListView.EndItemSwipe();` makes the swipe stay active. Tapping the `[$]` repaints the button itself but the card doesn't redraw *until* the swipe is closed by tapping the card:

[image: Stay-open flow]

So my question is how to force a refresh on the item card while it's still swiped, i.e. during the 3rd frame above not the 4th. (I've got lots of reasons for wanting to do this and this example simply demonstrates the basic core issue.)

Comment: If it helps answer the question you can [browse full sample on GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/update_list_view_swiped_item.git).

Comment: Any Layout class has a `ForceLayout()`. That might do it.

Comment: I hoped it would be something simple like that. Trying it now...

Comment: OK, so the `ListView` itself doesn't have a `ForceLayout()` but you said pass it up to the containing Layout. One sec while I event that...

Comment: Ok, so I handled the `PropertyChanged` event in the main view to call `ForceLayout()` and verified that it's getting called. No soap, unfortunately. I have to think that layout is already happening, otherwise the button wouldn't be changing color but it _is_. From appearances, it seems that the painting on the card is disallowed on purpose by design, or I should say deferred until the swipe close. It might not be possible, but that's where I need to get my hook in!

Comment: Yeah, not surprised. Given that Background OnPropertyChanged didn't cause change until later. Can you programmatically re-start the Swipe? If not, you'll need their source code. Or perhaps they have a custom renderer you can subclass on each platform.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I could figure out a way to cycle the swipe. I agree that could be a decent workaround. Oh and also thx for helping me get my `Student` badge lol.